# Mockito test - Context onject is null exception

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I don't know why but I get null pointer exception when running this code.
This is a really basic Mockito test which I copied from Android's official documentation.

Don't mind the logic. I made it super simple to show that even this basic example doesn't work

```
    package com.matala3.me.matala3;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import android.content.Context;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Mock_tests {

    private static final String FAKE_CONNECED_STRING = "Connected as";

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Before
    public void before(){
        Mockito.when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.connected_as))
                .thenReturn("Connected as");
    }

    @Test
    public void checkHeaderString() {

        assertThat("Connected as", is(FAKE_CONNECED_STRING));
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:476)
at com.matala3.me.matala3.ExampleInstrumentedTest.before(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:26)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```

Comment: You don't have `before()` method in your code.

Comment: @davidxxx It doesn't help even the anonating before method with `@before`and even when moving the `Mockito.when(mMock...` to there

Comment: No. What I means is you have a stacktrace that refers this method but this method is not in the shown code. To help you reliably, we need actual code.

Comment: I updated sorry

Comment: No problem. I did an answer. Not a rocket but It could help you probably.

Answer (score 2):

This statement :

```
Mockito.when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.connected_as))
       .thenReturn("Connected as");
```

provokes this exception :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a
>   null object reference

because `mMockContext` is `null`.
It means that the mocking initialization was not performed here :

```
@Mock
Context mMockContext;
```

I tested on my machine with Eclipse and Maven and I have the expected behavior : the mock is correctly initialized.

I could not explain the cause but I suspect a side effect with some classes or the way which you run the test (IDE maybe ?).
This first call  :

> android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)

refers to an instrumented test, that is, with device/emulator aware while you didn't write [a instrumented test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) as you mock device features.

So as advice : you could check you don't have configuration or dependencies that enable the instrumentation and try to execute it from command line to ensure that it is not a IDE issue.

Comment: Ok ! I have the impression that the way which you run the test is the issue. I edited. Second try !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mockito 2.x, the `org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner` is deprecated and `org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner` should be used.

If problem still exists you could initialize the `@Mocks` by adding this the `@Before` method:

```
@Before
public void before(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.connected_as))
            .thenReturn("Connected as");
}
```

**Update**:

I looked a bit at the [Context.getString(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) javadocs and it is a final method. There is not out-of-the-box support for mocking that kind of methods in Mockito.

You would need to use a [special plugin](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mockito-mock-maker-inline), or Powermock which is also explained on that link.

Comment: I tried the trick `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` it doesn't work. I can't find the dependencies for the new import statement of the new version.